# Why do I get a blank white page with a tilda and slash?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, server

When I start a live server I get this strange window where the background is white and there's a tilda and dash on the top left. The title of the window says "listing directory / " and I can see my files. This is what it looks like:

[Listing directory /](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egeQ7.png)

I can access all my files just fine, but why is it doing this, and how do I prevent it?

Comment: its showing 2 folders still, and its because `~/` means root directory

Comment: @Ghost Ops So how do I prevent this window from appearing again?

Comment: i don't get it, how did u end up into that page? its nothing, it just shows the files in the root directory

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.